# PowerShell: How to get access token in SharePoint 2016 on-prem

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

how to get access token using Powershell?
Environment: SharePoint 2016 on-prem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pnp cmdlets will be the best option for you if you want to access the token.

You can also directly include Pnp cmdlets in your existing Power Shell .

Just follow these basic steps to get your local machine configured with Pnp . You just need to import the modules that's it .

https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/networking_and_servers/9781787127999/7/ch07lvl1sec41/installing-and-working-with-pnp-powershell-cmdlets

Click here for more information -

[Get-PnpAccesToken](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpaccesstoken?view=sharepoint-ps)